# Facebook API: Is there way to know who/what created an Event

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

I am working with FQL to get events from the Facebook platform.

All is ok until I have to get the creator of the Event.

If you go here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event

You will see that you can get the creator id.

The problem is that it is not specified wherever the creator is a user, a page, a group or whatever. So when I go to take the details of the creator if it is not a user I get errors.

Is there a way to understand who is the creator? maybe via the ID?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get to know who the ID belongs to by requesting the [`profile`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/profile/) FQL table.

> **Type**: the type of profile, one of user, group, page, event, or application

#### Example:

```
SELECT name, type FROM profile WHERE id=11239244970
```

#### Result:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "stackoverflow", 
      "type": "page"
    }
  ]
}
```